# Logo appears locally but doesn't display properly when I deploy the app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, rsconnect

I have a logo I would like to display on the top right corner of my app and when I launch the app locally it displays properly.

However, when I try to deploy the app, everything works fine except that my logo is just a question mark and the title. The .png file is located in the www folder in the working directory.

This is a snippet of the code:

```
header <- dashboardHeader(title="XXX",
   tags$li(a(href = 'https://www.google.com',
             img(src = 'Google_logo.png', title = "Google Home", height = "30px"),
             style = "padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px"),
             class = "dropdown")
)
```

Any help on this one is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing src with `src =  base64enc::dataURI(file = "www/Google_logo.jpg", mime = "image/jpeg")`,  maybe saving logo as jpg. That did the trick for me, although why it worked I am not really sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help.

Comment: Is the `www` folder deployed at all?

Comment: Thanks for the inputs! In the end, it worked fine with the original formulation without me doing anything.